# Dealing with XML attributes transforming XML to JSON with "custom" strategy in Marklogic

Tags: json, xquery, marklogic

Attempting to transform the below XML using the custom strategy on Marklogic 9 but I'm running into issues with how the `json:transform-to-json()` function deals with attribute values.

Input XML:

```
<values>
       <option value="0">aaaa</option>
       <option value="1">bbbb</option>
       <option value="2">cccc</option>
 </values>`
```

The output JSON I desire:

```
{
  "values": {
    "0": "aaaa",
    "1": "bbbb",
    "2": "cccc"
  }
}
```

Here is my qcon code:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace json = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"
    at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";


let $xml := <values>
               <option value='0'>aaaa</option>
               <option value='1'>bbbb</option>
               <option value='2'>cccc</option>
            </values>

(: OUTPUT WANTED: "values": {
                    "0": "aaaa",
                    "1": "bbbb",
                    "2": "cccc"
                  } :)

let $custom :=
     let $config := json:config("custom")
     return 
       (map:put($config, "array-element-names", ("values", "option")),
        map:put($config, "text-value", ("answer")),
       $config)
return 
  json:transform-to-json(
      $xml, $custom
  )
```

The above script gives me an incorrect output of:

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "option": [
        {
          "value": "0",
          "answer": "aaa"
        },
        {
          "value": "1",
          "answer": "bbb"
        },
        {
          "value": "2",
          "answer": "ccc"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is with ONLY using the json:config options, is it possible to build my desired output? Or will I need to do some parsing pre or post transformation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that it is possible to achieve what you want using only `json:config` options and `json:transform-to-json()`.

You can achieve the desired output by using a [`json:object()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/json:object):

```
let $xml := <values>
               <option value='0'>aaaa</option>
               <option value='1'>bbbb</option>
               <option value='2'>cccc</option>
            </values>

let $object := json:object() 
return 
  ( 
    map:put($object, $xml/name(), map:new($xml/option/map:entry(@value, text()))), 
    xdmp:to-json($object) 
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The results requested require some amount of pre/post processing and/or a tedious level of configuration that, IMHO, is best avoided. (you can override individual transformation functions used in the transform-to-json ... but you need to know precisely how they are used and implemented -- available by reading the source).

You are requesting several kinds of transformations in one shot.
1)  structural transformation which collapses a complex element
2) using a value as an element name
3) using an invalid XML QName as a JSON field name. ("0", "1" ...)
The first can *can* be done by first transforming the XML into XML which is structurally equivilent to the desired json ... e.g.

```
<values>
    <_0>aaaaa<_0>
    <_1>bbbbbb<1>
     ....
 </values>
```

Then a transformation of the element names to json ("_0" -> "0" ... )

The later can be implemented by using an undocumented configuration value, "json-name-from-element-qname"  and/or "json-name-from-attribute-qname" , setting the value to your own function.

If it were me, I would write the transformation 'by hand' using either the json:object or literal JSON object creation syntax ( object { .. } ) for the JSON creation.  This would be simpler and more performant then attempting to trick transform-to-json into doing what you want.